# Retrieve and update attribute data from a list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, list

I am building a cloudpage to replace the standard subscription center. I want handle the email list subscriptions in there through checkboxes.

I am already stuck at visualizing the subscription lists.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
%%[
var myList = List.Init('Promotions')

var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"Email Address", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:"testSFMC@gmail.com"})
%%]
%%=v(@subs)=%%
```

When trying to generate the cloudpage, I get an internal server error. This indicates that something is wrong with AMPscript but I don't know what.

Edit: New code

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var promotions = List.Init('Promotions');

var subscriber = promotions.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"Email Address",SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:"matthias.claes@forward.eu"});

Variable.SetValue("subscriber", subscriber);
</script>
%%[
set @rowCount = rowcount(@subscriber)

var @status
var @subscriberKey
set @status = "empty1"
set @subscriberKey = "empty2"

if @rowCount > 0 then
  set @row = row(@subscriber,1) /* get row #1 */
  set @status = field(@row,"Status")
  set @subscriberKey = field(@row,"Subscriber Key")
endif
]%%

%%=v(@status)=%% <br>
%%=v(@subscriberKey)=%% <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not AMPScript, you are writing Server Sided JavaScript.
If you WERE using AMPScript, the closing tag should look like this though:
]%%

When working with lists, refer to the documentation for SSJS.
In general, working with lists is a lot harder than working with data extensions in this regard. probably not an option, just wanted to note it.

With that said, the following should be wrapping your code -
Start by loading the Core Library, otherwise the list.Subscribers method does not work:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listFunctions.htm

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
/* your code here */
</script>
```

If you want to display the "@subs" AMPScript variable, you can set the AMPSCript variable from Javascript using Variable.SetValue():

```
Variable.SetValue("subs",subs);
```

in sum, this would be my starting point (untested).

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var myList = List.Init('Promotions');
var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"EmailAddress",SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:"testSFMC@gmail.com"});
Variable.SetValue("subs",subs);
</script>
%%=v(@subs)=%%
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh didn't know that when working with lists it has to be SSJS! Thanks a lot!
I've updated my code to the following (see post), but it still returns "empty" for both attributes. How does SSJS deal with attributes that have spaces?